# Android Facebook SDK 3.0 - How to log in as another user?

Tags: android, facebook, logout, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the official Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android in my app.
I want to be able to disconnect and reconnect as a different user inside my application.
For the logout i use this code:

```
mSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

this is the code for login:

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
```

When I try to reconnect i don't see the facebook login activity but I login as the user has logged out.
How can I really be able to logout and subsequently log in as another user?

Comment: when you clear the session you don't logout from the Facebook native app which handles the access tokens for the SDK

Comment: so I can only logout with Facebook native app?

Comment: There was FORCE_AUTH_DIALOG in 2.0 SDK, I am searching for its replacement in new SDK also

Answer (score 0):

try to close the active session onDestroy method or try something like this

```
public void onDestroy() {
        this.closeSession();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```